# sub category check isn't working

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-spinner

I've taken another look at this and have done some changes. The problem, I'm facing is that the following like returns a NullPointerException:

```
_parseObject.getParseObject(subCategory).fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
```

When I step through the code, everything is populated as it should be... so now I'm stuck trying to figure out where the null exception is coming from.

Also, there must be a better way to handle onItemSelected. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
public class AddSubCategory extends Activity {
  protected Spinner     mCategoryList;
  protected EditText    mSubCategory;
  protected EditText    mDescription;
  protected Button      mSaveSubCategoryBtn;
  protected ParseObject categoryHolder;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sub_category);

    mCategoryList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categorySpinner);
    mSubCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subCategoryText);
    mDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    mSaveSubCategoryBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveSubCategoryButton);

    // populate the spinner with a list of categories
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
      new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
          ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Category");
          query.orderByAscending("Name");
          return query;
        }
      };
    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
    adapter.setTextKey("Name");
    mCategoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCategoryList.setSelection(1);

    mCategoryList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        // on selecting a category
        categoryHolder = (ParseObject) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent) {

      }
    });

    mSaveSubCategoryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(final View v) {
        final String subCategory = mSubCategory.getText().toString().trim();
        final String description = mDescription.getText().toString().trim();
        final ParseObject category = (ParseObject) mCategoryList.getSelectedItem();

        if (subCategory.isEmpty() || description.isEmpty()) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSubCategory.this);
          builder.setMessage("One of the required fields are empty.")
                 .setTitle("Empty Field")
                 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
          AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
          dialog.show();
        } else {
          // check to see if the sub-category exists
          ParseQuery<ParseObject> categoryQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category");
          categoryQuery.getInBackground(category.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(final ParseObject _parseObject, final ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                // Category found! Let's query for the subclass.
                _parseObject.getParseObject(subCategory).fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void done(final ParseObject _parseObject, final ParseException e) {
                    // subCategory found!
                    // String catName = _parseObject.getString("Name");
                    Log.d("Name", "The subCategory already exists.");
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSubCategory.this);
                    builder.setMessage("A subcategory already exists with this name.")
                           .setTitle("Duplicate Name")
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                  }
                });
              } else {
                // SubCategory does not exsit!
                ParseObject subCategoryObject = new ParseObject("SubCategory");
                subCategoryObject.put("Name", subCategory);
                subCategoryObject.put("Description", description);
                subCategoryObject.put("parent", categoryHolder);

                subCategoryObject.saveInBackground();
                Toast.makeText(AddSubCategory.this, "SubCategory created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mSubCategory.setText("");
                mDescription.setText("");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_sub_category, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the query. I changed it to:

```
 mSaveSubCategoryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    final String subCategory = mSubCategory.getText().toString().trim();
    final String description = mDescription.getText().toString().trim();
    final ParseObject category = (ParseObject) mCategoryList.getSelectedItem();

    if (subCategory.isEmpty() || description.isEmpty()) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSubCategory.this);
      builder.setMessage("One of the required fields are empty.")
             .setTitle("Empty Field")
             .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
    } else {//else01
      // check to see if the sub-category exists
      ParseQuery<ParseObject> subCategoryQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("SubCategory");
      subCategoryQuery.whereEqualTo("parent", category);
      subCategoryQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final ParseObject _parseObject, final ParseException e) {
          if (e == null){
            // subcategory exists
            Log.d("Name", "The subCategory already exists.");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSubCategory.this);
            builder.setMessage("A subcategory already exists with this name.")
                   .setTitle("Duplicate Name")
                   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
          }else{
            // SubCategory does not exist!
            ParseObject subCategoryObject = new ParseObject("SubCategory");
            subCategoryObject.put("Name", subCategory);
            subCategoryObject.put("Description", description);
            subCategoryObject.put("parent", categoryHolder);

            subCategoryObject.saveInBackground();
            Toast.makeText(AddSubCategory.this, "SubCategory created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSubCategory.setText("");
            mDescription.setText("");

          }
        }
      });
    }// end else01
  }
});
```

}

and now it works every time.